# Regex to find function name

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find the name of the last function applied on variable with the help of regex. For example:

```
aaa.test().other().mainFunction(a.test(),"test");
```

The regex match should give "mainFunction" as the output.

I tried with

```
/(.*)\.(\w+)\([ ,\w\(\)\.\"]*\)/
```

which was supposed to give the functionName in the group2 but I failed for the above arguements.

Can anyone suggest me a better regex for this purpose?

Comment: what should it return for `aaa.test().other().mainFunction(a.test(),"test").toString()` ?

Comment: If you are trying to parse JavaScript with regular expressions, don't. Unless you can restrict the expressions (statements?) you are parsing to a very small subset, parsing programming languages using regular expressions is a dead end.

Comment: @SabujHassan: It should give "toString"

Comment: @mzedeler: Well, I'm not parsing javascript, but a custom scripting langauge  which I feel would cause similar problem as you stated since the statements complexities would be similar.
Any other approach ?

Comment: The only way forward is to use a real parser. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) parser.

```
var jsp = require('uglify-js');

function lastMethod(js) {
  var ast = jsp.parse(js);
  return js + ': ' + ast.body[0].body.expression.end.value;
}

console.log(lastMethod('aaa.test().something(1, 2).new()'));
console.log(lastMethod('aaa.mainFunction(a(1), b(2))'));
```

This outputs:

```
aaa.test().something(1, 2).new(): new
aaa.mainFunction(a(1), b(2)): mainFunction
```

Comment: This was written before I realized that the language is *not* JavaScript (even though the question has the JavaScript tag).

Comment: Actually I'm writing code in JS only but not for js. That looks like to include another parser.
Wouldn't making a stack and iterating the line backward and push and pop the brackets work ? Or any other idea to avoid using other library?

Comment: Yes, you could use a stack as part of writing your own parser :-)